# How to create a SharePoint Content Type with multiple New Forms?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, jquery, office-365

I am working in SharePoint 2013. I am trying to create a content Type with multiple New Forms. If some users click the New Item link they have to see one form and for others if they click the link they have to see different New Form. Is it possible? If yes please let me know how to do this.

Comment: what difference between users?

Comment: For owners group one New Form and for Members group one form

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood was: Do you want to show different Forms for some users.

Use jquery to know the person, and separate items by divs. For example in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
If(people == 'Admin'){
$('#tableAdmin').show();
$('#tableUser').hide();
}else{
$('#tableAdmin').hide();
$('#tableUser').show();
}
}
```

Inside the Form, you open SharePoint Designer and open the list and open a Custom Form in advanced and is for example:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="tableAdmin">
<tr>
<td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
<H3 class="ms-standardheader">
<nobr>Example<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span>
</nobr>
</H3>
</td>
<td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">

...

</td>
</tr>
</table>






<table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="tableUser">
<tr>
<td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
<H3 class="ms-standardheader">
<nobr>Example<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span>
</nobr>
</H3>
</td>
<td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">

...

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```